# Redirecting print statements to a file

Tags: windows, testing, go

My program outputs a lot of text.

I use VSCode (relatively new) and the display of output is always truncated.

Is it possible to output all such fmt.PrintXXX statements to a file?

OR

How can I capture all of the output from the .Print statements ?

Comment: 1) Which OS you're using? 2) What have you tried so far?

Comment: Win10 OS. I looked through the settings VSCode to see if there was one I could toggle but did not see any. The testing package does not appear to have (i'm quite new) the ability to redirect output.

Comment: fmt.Print writes to stdout and you can redirect that e.g. with shell redirections. If you want your code to write to somewhere else you need to use fmt.Fprint.

Comment: where is your code and what is your expected output

Answer (score 0):

The way that I would recommend redirecting your output, would be to use the `fmt.Fprint*` family of functions, and specify an `io.Writer` that you want to write to. The io.Writer can be whatever you need, from an in memory buffer, to a file on your system, or even an open network connection. The `fmt.Print*` functions are implemented by calling the `fmt.Fprint*` functions and specifying `os.Stdout` as the `io.Writer`.

Because of the way the `fmt.Print*` functions are defined, it should technically be possible to set `os.Stdout` to a new `*os.File` in order to redirect the output of anything that writes to stdout, including the `fmt.Print*` functions. This is really not recommended, but possible.

https://play.golang.org/p/k5GzQIAYLcf